# How to encrypt large size files with commoncrypto in ios in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, aes, swift3

I am working on aes 128 encryption and decryption. I can encrypt smaller size files with commoncrypto. But I am not finding a proper solution to handle large file size with commoncrypto aes encryption.
please help me. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use file streaming with the Common Crypto functions: `CCCryptorCreateWithMode`, `CCCryptorUpdate`, `CCCryptorFinal` and `CCCryptorRelease`.

Or see [RNCryptor Incremental Usage](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor).